# BITS service is not starting, Windows Update always stuck at 0%

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, services

Windows update is always stuck at 0%. The BITS service always crashes immediately on start with code `-2147024894` / `0x80070002`
[image]
I have tried lots of things that worked for other people with this error

- Windows Update troubleshooter tells me it was unable to fix problems
- Renaming C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution doesn't change anything
- Using `regsvr32` on all the DLLs that Windows Update requires doesn't change anything
- `sfc /scannow` reports that everything is OK
- Running Software Update Readiness Tool does nothing

Answer (score 1):

After too many hours and too many reboots trying to solve this problem, I managed to figure out what it is. I haven't found this solution anywhere else, so I'm sharing here in the hopes that people who have this problem in the future don't need to spend as long as I did fixing it :)

I used [Systinternals Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx) and filtered on my instance of `svchost -k netsvcs`. When I attempted to start BITS it gave me 2 registry entries that resulted in `NAME NOT FOUND`

- `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Security\4a8aaa94-cfc4-46a7-8e4e-17bc45608f0a`
- `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\BackupRestore\FilesNotToBackup`

The first one turned out to be useless, but adding a key for the second one fixed the problem! It turns out that BITS was crashing because that key was missing and it needed to write values there.
I can now see BITS entries under that key:
[image]

**Update:** Windows Update still wasn't working even after I got BITS up. Turns out I needed another registry key which was missing, `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\WindowsUpdate`

Comment: Good man, thankyou!  this has just saved me hours of work.